# change from horiozntal scroll to vertical when mobile

Tags: jquery, horizontal-scrolling, vertical-scrolling

My website is responsive. When visited from a laptop it has horizontal navigation but when visited from mobile I would like to change the same scrolling animation but going vertical...

```
 <script>

$(function() {
    $('.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
        }, 500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


</script>
```

The website is www.niklaskoskela.com

Let me know if I need to provide anything else.

Kind regards

Answer (score 0):

Modificate your .js like this:

```
$(function() {
    $('.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var anchorOffset = $(this.hash).offset();
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: anchorOffset.left,
            scrollTop: anchorOffset.top // <- add this line
        }, 500);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});


</script>
```

and in .css add *media queries*:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1024px){
  #one, #two, #three {
    float: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: I couldn´t make that work. The scroll function ended up not working on either of them... Am I missing something? I have a media query for @media screen and (max-device-width: 960px 

Is that conflicting with it?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo mistake. Should be `.hash` instead of `.href`
Please check [working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/gregmatys/JtHj2/1/). Note that I used `display:inline-block` structure instead of `float:left`. If any questions, please ask.
Regarding second part of your question: I didn't note your media queries. It's not a problem. You can move `float: none` to yours. It doesn't matter.

Comment: I would love to, how?

Comment: :) Click on top arrow (on the left to my answer)

Comment: I need 15p reputation to "vote up", which I don´t seem to have... So sorry